# How do I install Google Gadgets?

Tags: 11.10, google

how to install google gadgets in ubuntu 11.10? Any ppa s available? .Source code is available on their website how to package it?
If it is not packaged yet ,how can i build it from source code?

Comment: I do not believe it is packaged for Upuntu 11.1 as yet: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/google-gadgets
But screenlets may be able to use google gadgets

Comment: This project looks dead - last upload Jan 2010 (http://code.google.com/p/google-gadgets-for-linux/downloads/list)

Comment: google stopped support for it, but old sourcecode is still availble

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a compilation exercise, it is just about possible to force google-gadgets to compile - however I'm doubtful whether google-gadgets for the desktop is *useful* since Google themselves has [discontinued support](http://googledesktop.blogspot.co.uk/)

Thus this answer will give you enough pointers to achieve this under 11.10:

[image]

---

**How to compile:**

Install the prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential bzr autoconf libtool

sudo apt-get install build-essential zip flex desktop-file-utils shared-mime-info zlib1g-dev libgtk2.0-dev libxml2-dev libdbus-1-dev librsvg2-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev network-manager-dev libqt4-dev libstartup-notification0-dev libltdl-dev libqt4-dev
```

**get the source**

```
cd ~/Downloads
bzr branch lp:googlegadgets
cd googlegadgets/
```

**to generate something to compile**

```
sh autotools/bootstrap.sh
./configure
```

**to compile**

Now - this isnt straightforward since there is various parts of the code that dont compile in 11.10.

Thus it is interative - fix and then run `make`.  Repeat this until it fully compiles.

The files to edit are:

```
gedit ggadget/gtk/single_view_host.cc &
gedit ggadget/dbus/dbus_utils.cc &
gedit extensions/gst_video_element/gadget_videosink.cc &
gedit extensions/linux_system_framework/network.cc &
gedit extensions/linux_system_framework/wireless.cc
```

To take a purist approach - you'll need to replace the code with 11.10 equivalents.  Taking the blunderbuss approach ... I just commented out the various sections, or where an `int` variable needs to be assigned - just assigned it a value of `0`.

Obviously - just commenting out code will leave these areas non-functional - I'll leave that to an interested person to investigate the 11.10 equivalents...

Use the make error to comment out the relevant sections ( 'C' comments are `/* ... */` and `// ...`)

**to install**

```
sudo make install
```

**to run**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
gg-qt &
```